# group by and pivot without aggregation in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to group by a value in pyspark.

Here is my sample data, 
Where i want to group by deviceID and ts(present in signalId column).

I want to aggregate data (Max) for each session started (ts) on each device(deviceId).

[image]

Expected output is

[image]

To achieve this, I need to pivot signalId without aggregation (sum, avg, max, min etc)
Then I need to group by signalId and ts and apply max aggregation to achieve my result.

But i am not able to apply pivot without aggregation.

sample data:

`df = sc.parallelize([['2020-04-07T15:50:36.618Z','A','p','Number of Packets','number','2'],
                    ['2020-04-07T15:50:36.618Z','A','d','Session Duration','s','3'],
                     ['2020-04-07T15:50:36.618Z','A','type','Connection Type','number','0'],
                     ['2020-04-07T15:50:36.618Z','A','ts','Time Session Started','ms','4/7/2020  3:50:36 PM'],
                     ['2020-04-07T15:51:37.127Z','A','p','Number of Packets','number','670810'],
                     ['2020-04-07T15:51:37.127Z','A','d','Session Duration','s','61'],
                     ['2020-04-07T15:51:37.127Z','A','type','Connection Type','number','0'],
                     ['2020-04-07T15:51:37.127Z','A','ts','Time Session Started','ms','4/7/2020  3:50:36 PM'],
                     ['2020-04-07T17:50:29.93Z','B','p','Number of Packets','number','3'],
                     ['2020-04-07T17:50:29.93Z','B','d','Session Duration','s','2'],
                     ['2020-04-07T17:50:29.93Z','B','type','Connection Type','number','1'],
                     ['2020-04-07T17:50:29.93Z','B','ts','Time Session Started','ms','4/7/2020  5:50:29 PM'],
                     ['2020-04-07T17:51:55.675Z','B','p','Number of Packets','number','2'],
                     ['2020-04-07T17:51:55.675Z','B','d','Session Duration','s','5'],
                     ['2020-04-07T17:51:55.675Z','B','type','Connection Type','number','1'],
                     ['2020-04-07T17:51:55.675Z','B','ts','Time Session Started','ms','4/7/2020  5:55:55 PM']
                    ]).toDF(("timestamp","deviceID","signalId","signalname","unit","value"))

df.show()`

Comment: could you post the sample dataset.its  hard to reproduce without data.

Comment: Updated with sample data. Hope it helps.